# failure in client-server communication in c

Tags: c, arrays, winsock

I am trying a C program for communication between client and server. I want my server to randomly generate an array, send it to the client and get back the sorted array from client to server. But, when I print the array sent by the server, the client shows only zeros. I guess there is problem either send function in server or receive/read function in client. Here is my code:

Server Side:
1- to create a random array

```
    //int ip[255];
    void GenIpArray()//generate random values and store in ip[]
        {
            for(int i=0;i<255;i++)
                {
                    ip[i]= rand()%100 + 100;
                }
        }
```

2- to send array to the client

```
void write(LPVOID sock_fd)//int sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    {
        while(1)
            {
                send((int)sock_fd,(char*)&ip,255,0);
                //let int ip[255] = {123, 109, 240, 150};
            }
    }
```

Client Side:
1- to receive from server

```
void read(LPVOID sock_fd)
    {
        while(1)
            {
                if(recv((unsigned int)sock_fd,(char*)&arr,255,0)>0)
                {
                    printf("recevied: ");
                    strcpy((char*)x, (char*)arr);
                    printf("%c",(char *)&x);//this statement prints @       
                    printArray();//function to print array  
                    break;
               }
           }
    }
```

2- function to print the array

```
    void printArray()
        {
            printf("\n\n Printing the array:\n");
            for(int k=0;k<255;k++)
                printf("\n %d",x[k]);
        }
```

Comment: How are defined `ip` and `arr`?

Comment: i tried removing & but no change in output. I declared arr as int arr[255]; and ip as int ip[255]; and x is int x[255];

Comment: You did not post enough: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sizeof(ip) is not 255, but sizeof(int)*255, try to use that as size in send()/recv()

Comment: You need to capture/print/debug the actual return value of `recv` and `send`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to `send` the correct size:

```
send((int)sock_fd, (char *)ip, 255 * sizeof(int), 0);
```

Then, you need to `recv` the correct size, reading it straight into `x`:

```
size_t bytes_received = recv((int)sock_fd, (char *)x, 255 * sizeof(int), 0);
```

Now `x` contains `bytes_received / sizeof(int)` numbers:

```
size_t ints_received = bytes_received / sizeof(int);
```

So you can use this number to loop and print them:

```
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < ints_received; k++) {
    printf("%d\n", x[k]);
}
```

For portability, you should really be converting your `int`s to network byte order with `htons` before sending them, and then converting them back to host byte order with `ntohs` after receiving them.

Comment: I have assigned ip and x as 'int ip[255];' and 'int x[255]; ', VS 2010 shows an error, says: "int * is incompatible with parameters of type const char* "

Comment: Ah, Windows. OK, do cast it, but don't treat it as a `char*` by using `strcpy()` or anything like that on it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply the use of `strcpy`! It stops copying on first null, and you are sending ints between 100 and 200. So at best only first byte will end in `x` and all the other bytes will be what was there at the beginning (0 for static duration arrays).

**Never, ever use `strcpy`** for binary data, but only `memcpy`

And that's not all:

- you should allways control the return values of send and receive.
- `printf("%c",(char *)&x);` is non sense: you print the first byte of the address or `x` array
- if `ip` and `arr` are *real* arrays (not pointers) use directly `sizeof(ip)` and `sizeof(arr)`

  ```
  send((int)sock_fd,(char*)ip,sizeof(ip),0);
  recv((unsigned int)sock_fd,(char*)arr,sizeof(arr),0)
  ```